# Sending a message from Cobol to Java with Binary AND Character fields

Tags: java, ibm-mq, cobol

How do I handle this? A Java program sends a message to my Cobol program with a key to a VSAM record. My program retrieves the record and sends it back to Java. But the record has four COMP-2 (hex) fields on it which get mangled during MQ delivery. How do I get MQ to NOT translate the four hex fields? I'm not an MQ guru but I'm not afraid to try anything.

Comment: The most reasonable approach would be to unpack any non-DISPLAY fields, the easiest place to do so is COBOL with a `MOVE CORRESPONDING SOME-REC TO UNPACKED-REC`. If you want that binary data send via MQ: do BASE64 on the complete record, that's easy to "undo" on the other side (which would possibly still have to handle the binary data in a "special" way afterwards).

Comment: Comp-2 fields are a mainframe only format, you need to translate to Text. Simon's `MOVE CORRESPONDING` solution is the way to go. You may need to do something special for the comp-2 (floating point fields). Copy the existing copybook, remove all comp, comp-3 from the copybooks. Comp-1, Comp-2 will require special handling

Comment: If you set the MQMD.Format to MQNONE then MQ won't try and convert from EBCDIC to ASCII.  You would then need to do the conversion in your Java program of the text fields.

Comment: Or create a data conversion exit that understands the format of your message, then it will convert the string fields from EBCDIC to ASCII and the COMP-2 fields (floating point right?) from s390 to IEEE or whatever you need done to them. Or even just leave them exactly alone. Since you create the exit, you decide. It's fairly easy, there's even a utility to help you - `crtmqcvx` (read https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=exits-writing-data-conversion-exit-mq-windows)

Comment: Great ideas. Thank you all. I decided to move the COMP-2 field 2 times. The first move is to a PIC 9(10) field, which will truncate a decimal portion to the right of the radix point, and the second move will be to a PIC V9(10) field Which will truncate everything to the left of the  Radix point. I will then send them in an MQ message from the mainframe to the Java platform, allowing the EBCDIC to ASCII conversion to take place on fields that are completely alphanumeric.

Any cautionary thoughts? I’m told the numbers are interest rates and will never be bigger than 10 in either direction.

Comment: MQ will convert the message as a whole,  it does not have a concept of fields without a conversion exit.  If the numbers are stored as numeris in EBCDIC it would be fine as if would get converted to ASCII.

Comment: I found a better solution during testing today. I am allowed to move a Comp-2 field to a character work field with a picture of PIC -.9(16)E-99   This turns out to be a character string that can be transformed successfully by MQ during the sending of a message from an EBCDIC mainframe to an ASCII Java platform. I also tried PIC -.9(17)E-99 but that threw a compile error because the mantissa was larger than 16 digits. When my counterpart on the Java side received a number like +.1112223334445556E+16, he was able immediately to receive it as either an IEEE floating point OR a Java Double field.

Comment: Your Java counterpart should receive the number as a BigDecimal, or some precision might be lost in the translation.  Otherwise, yes, you as the COBOL developer have to present everything in a message as alphanumeric so the EBCDIC to ASCII translation works.